# Elm: Update a command coming from nested module

Tags: elm

In my Elm app, there is a parent and a child. I would like the child to send an HTTP command and then the parent would update it on the fly by adding the backend config that the child model doesn't have.

The way I see it is:

1. The child sends the HTTP command (update function)
2. The command is transferred to the parent (update function)
3. The parent adds the config to command (is this possible??)
4. The command is finally executed with all the required parameters

I would like to implement HTTP actions in children modules so my app remains modular while keeping the config in one place.

Any help is welcome. Maybe a different approach can solve my problem too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep all the configuration details in a module that handles the Http Requests. For example, you can have this code in Requests.elm

```
import Http
import Task

url = "http://ip.jsontest.com/"


getIP : (String -> msg) -> Cmd msg
getIP tagger = 
  Http.getString url
  |> Task.perform (\e -> tagger (toString e)) tagger
```

and then in the Component code have something like

```
update msg model =
  case msg of 
    GetIP -> model ! [Requests.getIP ShowIP]
    ShowIP str -> {model | ipStr = str} ! []
```

all the configuration details are hidden from the component. Only an API of access is exposed.

LATER EDIT:

Another option would be to define and pass around a dynamic Context. You can manage this context at the top level and just pass the current version around when you update things. It would look like this

In Requests.elm

```
import Http
import Task

type alias Context =
  { url : String }

getIP : Context -> (String -> msg) -> Cmd msg
getIP ctx tagger = 
  Http.getString ctx.url
  |> Task.perform (\e -> tagger (toString e)) tagger
```

in Components:

```
update ctx msg model =
  case msg of 
    GetIP -> model ! [Requests.getIP ctx ShowIP]
    ShowIP str -> {model | ipStr = str} ! []
```

Comment: Thanks that's helpful. But in your example the config is hardcoded. In my app the config is set by an incoming port during the init. I can't just import this module and call a function because the config is not in the child's scope.